# htaccess force ssl/https and non-www while allowing for framework routing to /public

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, mod-rewrite, https

Currently I have an htaccess in the root (public_html) that has the following rule:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*) public/$1 [L]
```

The `pubic_html/public` folder holds the assets while the `public_html/application` folder holds the MVC items. I am currently using these rules to force non-www inside of the `public_html/public` folder

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The current setup has this effect

```
http://www --> http://non-www
http://non-www --> http://non-www
https://www --> http://non-www
https://non-www -> https://non-www
```

Which is the desired effect in terms of enforcing non-www but I would also like to enforce ssl/https. When implementing the following rules in the `public` folder

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

I end up with the following results

```
http://www --> https://non-www/public/
http://non-www --> https://non-www/public/
https://www --> https://non-www/public/
https://non-www -> https://non-www/public/
```

So the non-www and ssl/https are being enforced but all are now also putting the `public` folder into the URL, which it should not be, just silently creating a vhost route to it instead.

I have tried various configurations of these rules, inside the `public_html` folder, the `public` folder, different rule orders etc but nothing is giving me the desired effect.

Could someone please help me figure out how to have all these rules work nicely together? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried combining these rules to your original force non-www rule? So: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC,OR]` and then below `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on`. So it is two conditions to just the one Rewrite. Ending with `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]`

Comment: @Joe sorry that doesnt work. I get ERR_INVALID_REDIRECT from Chrome and it doesnt redirect http://non-www to https://non-www anyways...

Comment: It's strange that it does that considering that your original Rewrite works fine.. we're just adding an `[OR]` to the condition.

Comment: Well `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]`  makes back reference to the RewriteCond regex variable (%1), which in the case of `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on` doesn't exist. Perhaps thats why?

Comment: I ended up finding a solution and posting it as an answer to this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much trial and error I have managed to find a way that seems to work! I have no idea if this is specific to my setup but hopefully this will help someone else having similar issues.

I applied the following set of rules for redirecting all requests to a non-www and https version of the url. Visitors will always end up on https://example.com, regardless of having typed http, https, non-www, www or any combination thereof.

```
RewriteEngine on
# Redirect all www to https://non-www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
# Redirect http to https
RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Having http://www to https://non-www was as simple as adding the "s" on the rewrite rule, this avoids a double bounce of first going to http://non-www and then being told to visit https://non-www instead. https://www is also matched and told to bounce to https://non-www, so that covers the http/s + www mutations.

The only https checking rule that seems to work for my setup was to use `%{ENV:HTTPS}` since `%{HTTPS}` and `%{SERVER_PORT} 80` did not work, I ended up with "invalid redirect" or "too many redirect" errors from the browser.

My setup (having another htaccess rule to redirect requests to the `public` folder) also required the use of `https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1` in the final line of rules. Most suggestions are to use `https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}` but in my case the `%{REQUEST_URI}` included the `public` folder, which it should not. So using `$1` instead gave it the url that was already rewritten, instead of the actual request that the server sees.

I now have the following results:

```
http://www --> https://non-www (uses www to non-www rules)
http://non-www --> https://non-www (uses http to https rules)
https://www --> https://non-www (uses www to non-www rules)
https://non-www -> https://non-www (does not redirect)
```